# Xamarin Binding DataContext object Path=. force update

Tags: xamarin.forms, label, converters, datacontext

I have a viewmodel with two properties like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected string _aaa;
    protected string _bbb;

    public string AAA
    {
        get { return _aaa; }
        set
        {
            _aaa = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(AAA));
        }
    }
    public string BBB
    {
        get { return _bbb; }
        set
        {
            _bbb = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(BBB));
        }
    }

 /// etc.…..
}
```

I also have a view whose bidningcontext is an object of type MyViewModel:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <Label Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Label1" Text="{Binding AAA}" />
         <Label Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Label2" Text="{Binding Path=. , Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
 </Grid>
```

And the converter uses both property AAA and BBB to return a string value.

Everything works fine at the initialisation. When AAA property changed, the label1 changes its value accordingly, but I need to force Label2 to update its value by calling the converter too if AAA or BBB changed. But as the binding is done with the datacontext directly (Path=.) and not one of its property, it actually never updates its text property.

Does anyone has a clue how to solve my pb?
Thanks you in advance for any help.

Comment: What does the converter do? If it is only formatting a string, I would suggest putting another string property that creates the desired string and when either `AAA` or `BBB` changes, you also `RaisePropertyChanged` on that property.

Comment: thank you for your response, but I thought about this solution, but I need to update the Label2 value using the converter. Is there a means to force label2 to update its value in Xamarin?

Comment: I'm not sure of a way to `RaisePropertyChanged` on your ViewModel instance. If at all possible I would suggest trying to use a separate property. If that's not possible, I'm not sure how to get `Label2` to update correctly..

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do... To reset it hard you could set the `BindingContext` again by doing `BindingContext = this;` but this will bind everything again. So doing that too much might cause performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Add a property in your view-model, let's say `Self`, that returns a reference to it's own instance; and make sure to raise property-changed event for the same when `AAA` or `BBB` is updated.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected string _aaa;
    protected string _bbb;

    public string AAA
    {
        get { return _aaa; }
        set
        {
            _aaa = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(AAA));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Self));
        }
    }
    public string BBB
    {
        get { return _bbb; }
        set
        {
            _bbb = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(BBB));
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Self));
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel Self
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

 /// etc.…..
}
```

Now, you can change your XAML to following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <Label Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Label1" Text="{Binding AAA}" />
     <Label Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Label2" Text="{Binding Path=Self, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you everybody for your suggestions. I thought maybe use UpdateSourceEventName but I do not find a lot of documentation about it. @Ada, I will try your proposal, thank you. I let you know when I'm done.